# How can I create many columns after a list in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe, I want to create a lot of new columns after a list and filled with `0`, how can I do it?

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["computer", "printer"]})
print(df)
>>>          a
>>>0  computer
>>>1   printer
```

I have a list

```
myList=["b","c","d"]
```

I want my new dataframe looks like:

```
>>>          a  b  c  d
>>>0  computer  0  0  0
>>>1   printer  0  0  0
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fastest solution:

```
for col in myList:
    df[col] = 0

print(df)
          a  b  c  d
0  computer  0  0  0
1   printer  0  0  0
```

Another solution is use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
pd.concat([df3,pd.DataFrame(columns=myList, index=df.index, data=0)], axis=1)
```

---

**Timings**:

*[20000 rows x 300 columns]*:

```
In [286]: %timeit pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(columns=myList)], axis=1).fillna(0)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.17 s per loop

In [287]: %timeit pd.concat([df3,pd.DataFrame(columns=myList, index=df.index,data=0)],axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 81.7 ms per loop

In [288]: %timeit (orig(df4))
10 loops, best of 3: 59.2 ms per loop
```

Code for timings:

```
myList=["b","c","d"] * 100
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["computer", "printer"]})
print(df)
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
df3 = df.copy()
df4 = df.copy()

df1= pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(columns=myList)], axis=1).fillna(0)

df2 = pd.concat([df3,pd.DataFrame(columns=myList, index=df.index, data=0)], axis=1)

print(df1)
print(df2)

def orig(df):
    for col in range(300):
        df[col] = 0
    return df

print (orig(df4))
```

Answer (score 1):

It'll be more performant to `concat` an empty df for large dfs rather than incrementally adding new columns as this will grow the df incrementally rather than just make a single allocation of the final df dimensions:

```
In [116]:
myList=["b","c","d"]
df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(columns=myList)], axis=1).fillna(0)
df

Out[116]:
          a  b  c  d
0  computer  0  0  0
1   printer  0  0  0
```

Comment: Hmmm, I think `concat` solution is faster, but not. Very interesting.

Comment: @jezrael that is surprising too, I would expect incrementally growing the df to be non-performant here